# How to find and delete a menu item in php?

Tags: php, css, html

I have a menu item that's linked to its children in my html.

```
<div class="collapse navbar- 
collapse 
navbar-ex1-collapse"><ul id="menu" 
class="menu"><li id="menu-item- 
3530" class="menu-item menu-item- 
type-post_type menu-item-object- 
page 
menu-item-has-children menu-item- 
3530 dropdown"><a title="Contact"  
href="https://4309.co.uk/conta
ct/">Contact 
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown- 
menu">
```

Basically I want to remove the word `contact` I've tried with css, it doesn't work. Where would i find this in my php and how would I remove that word. It keeps showing up in my `contact` page [here](https://4309.co.uk%20contact) top left in dropdown menu when it's opened.

Comment: Basically, it is setup in appearance -> menu => the menu you are using to display in that parts. But it also depends on your theme design such as custom code.

Comment: Yes, it's a header menu item which I've tried to hide. It seems WordPress stipulates you must have a header menu item, which i don't want. Is there a way to get rid of it because if I delete it, I'll have another header menu item. All the other menu items are sub menu items but having that header menu item messes it all up. Also, i can't target it with css to hide it.

Comment: It doesn't respond to css individually , it's out of positioning, if i remove it all my css goes haywire.

Comment: So i wondered if i can target it through php?

Comment: @simongcc unless you can tell me what the css selector would be? Because I've tried almost every selector there is and it just doesn't respond.